# Secret Santa using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a code to pick Secret Santas for my cousins. The code I have so far only works for an even number of people, but I have an odd number or cousins.

```
import random

def Santa(names, draw):
  matches= []
  while names:
    giver = names.pop() #chooses giver and removes name
    receiver = random.choice(draw) #picks random to receive

    if giver != receiver:
      matches.append([giver, receiver]) #adds pair
      draw.remove(receiver) #removes person from receiving list
    else:
      names.append(giver) #if names are the same, adds name back to list
  return matches

family1=['cousin1', 'cousin2', 'cousin3', 'cousin4']
family2=['cousin5', 'cousin6', 'cousin7','cousin8','cousin9','cousin10']
family3=['cousin11', 'cousin12', 'cousin13','cousin14']
family4=['cousin15', 'cousin16', 'cousin17']
family5=['cousin18', 'cousin19']

names = [ 'cousin1', 'cousin2', 'cousin3', 'cousin4','cousin5']

print(Santa(names,names))
```

The error is IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
from the line:

```
receiver = random.choice(draw)
```

One of the constraints I will add in the future is that you can't have one of your siblings or in-laws. Any advice on how to make this work for an odd list of names or the family constraint would be very helpful.

EDIT:

Here is my final code if anyone was looking to do the same thing.

```
import random
from copy import copy

def Santa(names, draw):
  matches= []
  while names:
    giver = names.pop()
    receiver = random.choice(draw)

    if giver[0] != receiver[0]:
      if giver[1] != receiver[1]:
        matches.append([giver, receiver])
        draw.remove(receiver)
    else:
      names.append(giver)
  return matches

family1=['cousin1', 'cousin2', 'cousin3', 'cousin4']
family2=['cousin5', 'cousin6', 'cousin7','cousin8','cousin9','cousin10']
family3=['cousin11', 'cousin12', 'cousin13','cousin14']
family4=['cousin15', 'cousin16', 'cousin17']
family5=['cousin18', 'cousin19']

names = [ ('cousin1', 'parent1'), ('cousin2', 'parent1'), ('cousin3', 'parent1'),('cousin4','parent1'),('cousin5','parent2'),('cousin6','parent2'),('cousin7','parent2'),
         ('cousin8','parent3'),('cousin9','parent3'),('cousin10','parent3'),('cousin11','parent4'),('cousin12','parent4'),('cousin13','parent4'),('cousin14','parent5'),
         ('cousin15','parent5'),('cousin16','parent2'),('cousin17','parent2'),('cousin18','parent3'),('cousin19','parent3'),('cousin20','parent2')]

print(Santa(names,copy(names)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've passed the same `names` array to both arguments. This may seem valid but you have to recall that Python passes arguments by reference so these are not two identical objects, they are the *same* object. When you pop an item from `givers` it also disappears from `draw`. Try the following:

```
import random
from copy import copy

def Santa(names, draw):
  matches= []
  while names:
    giver = names.pop() #chooses giver and removes name
    receiver = random.choice(draw) #picks random to receive

    if giver != receiver:
      matches.append([giver, receiver]) #adds pair
      draw.remove(receiver) #removes person from receiving list
    else:
      names.append(giver) #if names are the same, adds name back to list
  return matches

family1=['cousin1', 'cousin2', 'cousin3', 'cousin4']
family2=['cousin5', 'cousin6', 'cousin7','cousin8','cousin9','cousin10']
family3=['cousin11', 'cousin12', 'cousin13','cousin14']
family4=['cousin15', 'cousin16', 'cousin17']
family5=['cousin18', 'cousin19']

names = [ 'cousin1', 'cousin2', 'cousin3', 'cousin4', 'cousin5']

print(Santa(names,copy(names)))
```

Of course you won't actually need to do this when you move on to using different lists for the two arguments.